# Compress bash script to one line

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get GCP region information and based on that picking a GCS bucket to pull data from. The script looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe

GCP_REGION=$(curl -sf -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone | cut -d/ -f 4 | sed 's/.\{2\}$//')
BUCKET_NAME="foo-bar-"

case $GCP_REGION in
  us*)      BUCKET_NAME+="us";;
  asia*)    BUCKET_NAME+="asia";;
  europe*)  BUCKET_NAME+="eu";;
  *)        echo -n "unknown GCP region"; exit 1;;
esac

echo -n $BUCKET_NAME
```

Is there a way to compress it to one-liner statement?

Comment: Why do you need it in one line? You can make a script out of it and call that.

Comment: You can use `;` and `&&` to separate commands which are on the same line.

Comment: @Gergely I have to use it one time only in many different projects and there's no way to put it in a central place and per the use case it'd look neat to have it in a single line

Comment: @Gergely Another case: Embed into ``Exec`` entry in ``.desktop`` file for only one file.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the shebang, add a `;` at the end of every non-empty line that doesn't end in `;;` or `in`, then join all the lines together:

```
set -xe; GCP_REGION=$(curl -sf -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone | cut -d/ -f 4 | sed 's/.\{2\}$//'); BUCKET_NAME="foo-bar-"; case $GCP_REGION in us*)      BUCKET_NAME+="us";; asia*)    BUCKET_NAME+="asia";; europe*)  BUCKET_NAME+="eu";; *)        echo -n "unknown GCP region"; exit 1;; esac; echo -n $BUCKET_NAME;
```

We'll have to agree to disagree on the "look neat" aspect :-). Good luck!

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your answer. I actually did the same but then got stuck with string concatenation, took an hour to figure out `+=` doesn't work in `sh` and now `curl` is not there in alpine Linux and I can't install it. Tough day huh

Comment: You're welcome. idk about any of that, I just answered your question of how to get that script onto 1 line. if you need help doing whatever you wanted `+=` to do or installing `curl` on some system then ask new questions about those things.